# MySql query to join uuid that's stored differently between tables

Tags: mysql, sql, uuid, guid

I have a uuid that's stored in one table as a human-readable guid, but in another table it's split into upper and lower bits. How can I write a query to join the tables on the uuid?

**Edit:** table2 will only have 1 result with the given upper & lower bits, so hopefully efficiency shouldn't be too terrible, but please factor this into answers.

```
table1.uuid = 'b33ac8a9-ae45-4120-bb6e-7537e271808e'
table2.upper_bits = -5531888561172430560, table2.lower_bits = -4940882858296115058
```

I need to retrieve `table2.status` along with `table1.*` where `table2.upper_bits + table2.lower_bits = table1.uuid` (pseudo where statement) but I don't know how to either sum the table2 upper & lower values for the join, or how to convert table1's uuid to bits for the join.

Thanks!

Comment: @Strawberry unfortunately it's the db structure I inherited on a given project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this might work... but would obviously be highly inefficient.

```
SELECT ...
FROM table1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON REPLACE(t1.uuid, '-', '') 
                         = CONCAT(HEX(t2.upper_bits), HEX(t2.lower_bits))
...
```

...you might to force upper/lower case depending on collation/comparison.

---

I'd kind of lean toward it being "absolutely necessary" to change your database structure (to respond to a comment you made on another answer). To minimize the impact on existing queries and logic, you could change one of the tables to have additional matching fields to the other, and add triggers to the table to automatically populate/update the new fields; and then do a one time update to set all the old records' values.

*I'd try to go with modifying t1 first, since an index on two ints is likely "better" than on one string; but I'm not sure how straight-forward converting the string to the upper and lower bits would be.*

*Modifying t2 would be easier, the triggers would be little more than `SET NEW.uuid = CONCAT(HEX(NEW.upper_bits), HEX(NEW.lower_bits));` ...I say "little more than" because it would be best for the trigger to also insert the `-`'s at the expected points as well so the join condition could eliminate all function use.*

---

Edit: I found a way to calculate the bits in pure SQL:

```
SELECT @uuid := REPLACE('b33ac8a9-ae45-4120-bb6e-7537e271808e', '-', '') AS uuid
   , -1 * CAST((~CAST(CONV(SUBSTRING(@uuid, 1, 16), 16, 10) AS SIGNED) + 1) AS SIGNED) AS upper_bits
   , -1 * CAST((~CAST(CONV(SUBSTRING(@uuid, 17, 16), 16, 10) AS SIGNED) + 1) AS SIGNED) AS lower_bits
;
```

You may be able to use something like this in triggers for t1, and a one time update for t1 for the new fields.

...it might even help with the join:

```
ON -1 * CAST((~CAST(CONV(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(t1.uuid, '-', ''), 1, 16), 16, 10) AS SIGNED) + 1) AS SIGNED) 
  = t2.upper_bits
AND -1 * CAST((~CAST(CONV(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(t1.uuid, '-', ''), 17, 16), 16, 10) AS SIGNED) + 1) AS SIGNED) 
  = t2.lower_bits
```

Note: Yes, the excessive casting in both of these appears to be necessary (at least on the older version of MySQL I tested the calculation against.)

Comment: I have edited the question to include the following info: table2 will only have 1 result with the given upper & lower bits, so hopefully efficiency shouldn't be too terrible. In this case, will the efficiency still suffer drastically? Could a different type of join significantly improve efficiency given this info?

Comment: The efficiency problem is that both sides (one side is bad enough) need processed for the join; completely eliminating the possibility of using indexes... that it is a string comparison doesn't help either.

Comment: Table2 having only one result may not help that much as the db will still need to inspect (and calculate a string from) every row in t2 to find the right one.

Comment: As stated, the performance of this query is remarkably bad, even as an outer join. I've selected your answer as you answered my question precisely, but it appears we will be modifying the db structure. Thanks!

Comment: @Chad see edit, I add some more calculations you may be able to use.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation of @Uueerdo's solution that should be more efficient (sort of a decorate-join-undecorate), but I haven't run the EXPLAINs to know for sure:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.status
FROM (
  SELECT UUID_TO_BIN(uuid) AS tmpid, *
  FROM table1
) AS t1 INNER JOIN (
  SELECT UUID_TO_BIN(CONCAT(HEX(upper_bits), HEX(lower_bits))) AS tmpid, status
  FROM table2
) AS t2 ON t1.tmpid = t2.tmpid
```

It might use a bit more memory, which is something to keep in mind if the tables have many rows and/or if table1 is very wide.

If you only need the records from table1 and table2 matching a single UUID, you should just execute two queries, not a join:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE UUID_TO_BIN(uuid) = UUID_TO_BIN(?)

SELECT status
FROM table2
WHERE UUID_TO_BIN(CONCAT(HEX(upper_bits), HEX(lower_bits))) = UUID_TO_BIN(?)
```

If `upper_bits` and `lower_bits` are indexed, this would be a better way to query table2:

```
SET @tmpid = UUID_TO_BIN(?);

SELECT status
FROM table2
WHERE upper_bits = @tmpid >> 64, lower_bits = _binary X'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF' & @tmpid
```

And you could apply similar logic to my first solution (I think):

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.status
FROM (
  SELECT 
    UUID_TO_BIN(uuid) >> 64 AS upper_bits,
    _binary X'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF' & UUID_TO_BIN(uuid) AS lower_bits,
    *
  FROM table1
) AS t1 INNER JOIN (
  SELECT upper_bits, lower_bits, status
  FROM table2
) AS t2 ON t1.upper_bits = t2.upper_bits AND t1.lower_bits = t2.lower_bits
```

None of this is tested but hopefully it gives you some ideas to play around with.

Comment: MySql is stating that the table might be corrupted when I attempt the UUID_TO_BIN() logic ya got here. Nonetheless, this answer may help passersby and for that I'm giving an upvote. Cheers

Comment: @Chad Hrrm, on which line of which example?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to store lower_bits & upper_bits in table1 together with the uuid. Then join the tables on lower_bits & upper_bits.

**Edit**: If you need only a single row, and you are sure, that there will be a single matching row in the other table, then calculate the uuid= @uuid, lower_bits =@lbits & upper_bits= @ubits, and then run the following:

```
Select t1.*, t2.status  
From  
(select * from table1 where uuid = @uuid)  as t1
Cross join  
(select status from table2 where lower_bits =@lbits and upper_bits= @ubits) as t2;
```

Comment: This option will only be considered after exploring the question's plausibility, as I am told not to modify the db structure unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Chad I have updated my reply, according to your edited question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused. Are you saying to pass the uuid, lower bits, and upper bits? Is there a way to calculate the lower & upper bits inside the sql statement? I'm unable to send 3 parameters because there is exactly one match inside table2 for the uuid, but I'm pulling back numerous records from table1, with varying uuid values.

Comment: The uuid is supposed to be unique, so how do you have different uuid matches in table1 for a single uuid in table2?